# JasperReports Server "The job failed to execute"

Tags: jdbc, jasper-reports, jasperserver

I am new to *JasperReports Server* and have searched for a resolve to this issue. I have found nothing. I inherited this server and the reports are not running as scheduled.

```
Job: 3rd (ID: 61)
Report unit: /reports/Scheduled/00_Schedule_Primer
Quartz Job: ReportJobs.job_61
Quartz Trigger: ReportJobs.trigger_62_1
Exceptions:

An error occurred while executing the report.
com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.JSException: jsexception.error.creating.connection
    at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.engine.jasperreports.service.impl.JdbcDataSourceService.createConnection(JdbcDataSourceService.java:62)
    at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.engine.jasperreports.service.impl.BaseJdbcDataSource.setReportParameterValues(BaseJdbcDataSource.java:52)
    at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.engine.jasperreports.service.impl.JdbcDataSourceService.setReportParameterValues(JdbcDataSourceService.java:67)
    at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.engine.jasperreports.service.impl.EngineServiceImpl.fillReport(EngineServiceImpl.java:743)
    at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.engine.jasperreports.service.impl.EngineServiceImpl.fillReport(EngineServiceImpl.java:367)
    at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.engine.jasperreports.service.impl.EngineServiceImpl.executeReport(EngineServiceImpl.java:876)
    at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.engine.jasperreports.domain.impl.ReportUnitRequest.execute(ReportUnitRequest.java:60)
    at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.engine.jasperreports.service.impl.EngineServiceImpl.execute(EngineServiceImpl.java:301)
    at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.engine.scheduling.quartz.ReportExecutionJob.executeReport(ReportExecutionJob.java:444)
    at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.engine.scheduling.quartz.ReportExecutionJob.executeAndSendReport(ReportExecutionJob.java:372)
    at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.engine.scheduling.quartz.ReportExecutionJob.execute(ReportExecutionJob.java:188)
    at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:195)
    at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:520)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Middleware connect fail:No RPC Connection active.
    at com.ibm.u2.jdbc.UniJDBCMsgFactory.createException(UniJDBCMsgFactory.java:113)
    at com.ibm.u2.jdbc.UniJDBCExceptionSupport.addAndThrowException(UniJDBCExceptionSupport.java:62)
    at com.ibm.u2.jdbc.UniJDBCProtocolU2Impl.connect(UniJDBCProtocolU2Impl.java:746)
    at com.ibm.u2.jdbc.UniJDBCProtocolU2Impl.executeOpenDatabase(UniJDBCProtocolU2Impl.java:243)
    at com.ibm.u2.jdbc.UniJDBCConnectionImpl.<init>(UniJDBCConnectionImpl.java:116)
    at com.ibm.u2.jdbc.UniJDBCDriver.connect(UniJDBCDriver.java:111)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:582)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:185)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DriverManagerConnectionFactory.createConnection(DriverManagerConnectionFactory.java:48)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolableConnectionFactory.makeObject(PoolableConnectionFactory.java:290)
    at org.apache.commons.pool.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:771)
    at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolingDataSource.getConnection(PoolingDataSource.java:95)
    at com.jaspersoft.jasperserver.api.engine.jasperreports.service.impl.JdbcDataSourceService.createConnection(JdbcDataSourceService.java:58)
    ... 12 more
```

I don't even have a clue where to start troubleshooting this. ANY help would be awesome!

Answer (score 0):

It seems your connection url, username and password values are not proper.If these three things are proper then the connection will be created.Check in your Jasper server configuration.